# Pyspark - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while writing to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

when trying to write to a csv file using below code

```
DF.coalesce(1).write.option("header","false").option("sep",",").option("escape",'"').option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","false").mode("overwrite").csv(filename)
```

I am getting the below error

```
ileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Could someone advise a workaround ?

Comment: Is it necessary to coalesce into 1 file? If you're fine with multiple files, remove the `coalesce(1)` attribute

Comment: No I don't want multiple files this is the reason of using coalesce(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me adding the below spark config fixed the issue

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').config("spark.driver.memory", "15g").appName('sl-app').getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `executor.memory` in your spark-submit application

Something like this

```
spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

Comment: how do you know you must increase the executor-memory or the driver-memory?

Comment: There are a few factors to consider when deciding how much executor and driver memory to allocate for Spark applications. One important consideration is the size of the data set that will be processed. If the data set is large, then more memory will be needed for both the executors and the driver. Another consideration is the number of tasks that will be running in parallel. If there are many tasks, then more memory will be needed for both the executors and the driver